# Golang when i try to execute the command there is no output

Tags: go

I try to execute some commands (inside config.json)
Only npm commands have display output

This is my first time using Stackoverflow
Please forgive me if I did not do well

expected result:
when i write any command in config.json
will output the correct result

main.go

```golang
func main () {
    file, _ := os.Open("config.json")
    byteres, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    var config Config
    json.Unmarshal(byteres, &config)
    defer file.Close()

    process := exec.Command(config.StartCommand)
    stdout, _ := process.StdoutPipe()
    processscanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    processscanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    process.Start()
    go func() {
        for processscanner.Scan() {
            message := processscanner.Text()
            fmt.Println(message)
        }
    }()
}
```

config.json

```json
{
    "StartCommand": "npm"
}
```

Comment: Wait for your process to end. Your program exits before it can read the output.

Comment: Don't ignore errors. Your config file could not be readable, the json could be malformatted. You may not be able to get the StdoutPipe. you may not be able to start the command. In all of these cases, you are ignoring the error return value. And this would tell you important information.

Comment: If all you want to do is copy the output unmodified, you can simplify to `process.Stdout = os.Stdout; err := process.Run()` (instead of using the scanner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function isn't waiting for your goroutine to finish. Use [sync.WaitGroup](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) to block `main` until the goroutine is done.